# Как подцепить индекс?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица MYTABLE с полями A, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO. На ней есть составной уникальный индекс со всеми тремя полями MYTABLE (A, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO). Если писать запрос вида

```
SELECT *
  FROM MYTABLE 
  WHERE A = 100 
    AND DATE_FROM < SYSDATE
    AND DATE_TO > SYSDATE
```

То индекс успешно цепляется и стоимость очень низкая. Но если я хочу вывести все строки для сегодняшней даты:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MYTABLE 
  WHERE DATE_FROM < SYSDATE
    AND DATE_TO > SYSDATE
```

То индекс игнорируется. И запрос работает оооооооочень долго, т.к. очень много исторических не актуальных данных. Почему? Как бы индекс подцепить?

Comment: Попробуйте А>0 добавить. Индекс возможно сработает, но не факт что будет  быстрее и что индекс будет взят. На вопрос вы уже ответили - очень много == очень долго. Может индекс вообще в данном случае будет неэффективен. Речь едёт о первом фетче? А _оооооооочень долго_ это новая единица измерения времени? PS без реальных данных и плана выполнения это всё равно гадание на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 0):

Если индекс состоит из нескольких полей, то для того, чтобы индекс использовался оптимально в условии `WHERE` должно присутствовать минимум первое поле.

В вашем случае, надо перестроить индекс, чтобы даты были в начале и ли создать новый индекс.

Comment: Вот беда. Потому что индекс и таблица уже есть и новых не будет. Можно менять только сам запрос -.-

Comment: Хотя, честно говоря, я не уверен, что ваше предположение на сто процентов рабочее. Т.к. не важно ведь в какой последовательности заполнить WHERE в первом запросе, индекс все-равно подцепится.

Comment: Тут дело не в последовательности условий. В первом запросе есть поле А, оно первое в индексе, во втором поля A нет.

Comment: Занятно. Попробовал написать с хинтом SELECT /*+ index(MT MTINDEX)*/... - он действительно подцепил индекс... и заработал еще медленнее :D Как так то?)